# Как поменять Content-type в apache или nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, wsgi, content-type

Доброе время суток.

Есть Trac, есть необходимость поменять страницу списка проектов с простого html на xml.
Этому xml будет назначен xsl шаблон, тут проблемы нет.

Шаблон написан, все замечательно генерится, но возникает проблема в том, что trac рендерит ответ таким вот образом: `req.send(output, 'text/html')`.

Каким образом можно поменять этот content-type на text/xml? Иначе браузер не применяет xsl преобразование, нужен text/xml.

Перед апачем стоит nginx, который делает proxy_pass на апач.

Поменять content-type надо фактически только для одного пути, а именно /trac.

Кусок httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /trac d:/web/trac/apache/trac.wsgi

<Directory d:/web/trac/apache>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Кусок nginx.conf

```
server {
    location /trac {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/trac;
    }
}
```

Куда копать?

ЗЫ в трак лезть совсем нет желания.

ЗЗЫ Зачем такой изврат? Ну вот так фишка легла, связки-связки-связки...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Решил в nginx'е.

```
server {
    location = /trac/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/trac/;
        proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
        add_header Content-Type text/xml;
    }
    location /trac/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/trac/;
    }
}
```

ЗЫ Полдня мучился.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы переопределить тип содержимого, официальная документация Nginx рекомендует воспользоваться комбинацией директив types и default_type.

```
location /trac/ {
  types { }
  default_type application/xml;
}
```

https://nginx.org/r/types/ru

Comment: Круто. Спасибо. Попробовать правда уже негде )